# MongoDB Query - query on values of any key in a sub-object: $match combined with $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, list, filtering

How can I filter on all userIDs that have color blue and size 50 in the same element of the list? Only user 1347 should be output.

```
    {
        "userId": "12347",
        "settings": [
            { name: "SettingA", color: "blue", size: 10 },
            { name: "SettingB", color: "blue", size: 20 },
            { name: "SettingC", color: "green", size: 50 }
        ],    
     }
     {
        "userId": "1347",
        "settings": [
            { name: "SettingA", color: "blue", size: 10 },
            { name: "SettingB", color: "blue", size: 50 },
            { name: "SettingC", color: "green", size: 20 }
        ]    
     }
```

If this can be done with $elemMatch, how can I include it in the following query, assuming the following two elements needs to be in the same list:   { "rounds.round_values.decision" : "Fold"},
  { "rounds.round_values.gameStage" : "PreFlop"}

I tried this query but it doesn't yield any results. I've read that because elemMatch deosnt' work in projections. But how can I tell $filter to only return objects that have the $elemmMatch conditions met?

```
db.games.aggregate([ 
{ $match: { $and: [ 
  { Template: "PPStrategy4016" },
  { FinalOutcome: "Lost" }]
}},
{ $elemMatch: {
  { "rounds.round_values.decision" : "Fold"},
  { "rounds.round_values.gameStage" : "PreFlop"}
   } },
{ 
    $group: { 
        _id: null, 
        total: { 
            $sum: "$FinalFundsChange" 
        } 
    } 
} ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the given documents, the query is something such as follows:

```
db.games.aggregate( 
   {$unwind : "$settings"}, 
   {$match: {"settings.color" : "blue", "settings.size" : 50}} , 
   {$group: {_id: null, total: {$sum: "$settings.size"}}} )
```

If you have difficulties in transforming it into your own domain, pleas supply some example documents from your domain.

Comment: How does match know that color blue and size 50 need to be part of `the same` element? Isn't only $elemMatch doing that?

Comment: `$unwind` unfolds the array, followed by `$match` which is like and and query (color and size). `$elemMatch` doesn't apply to aggregation